# Need to create a function dynamically in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to create a new function in angularjs so I did something like below. I need to disable some elements in [angular tree control](http://wix.github.io/angular-tree-control/#isSelectable).

```
$scope.filterTreeOption = {
    dirSelectable: false,
    multiSelection: true,
    injectClasses: {
      "li": "injectedTreeLi"
    }
}

$scope.isFatalDisabled = false; $scope.isErrorDisabled = false; $scope.isWarnDisabled = false; $scope.isInfoDisabled = false; $scope.isDebugDisabled = false; $scope.isTomcatDisabled = false; $scope.isAgentDisabled = false; $scope.isSessionDisabled = false; $scope.isActivityDisabled = false;

// Another function here which changes above boolean property to true if needed.

var func = function(node) {
  var tmp = (node.label.indexOf("Fatal") !== 0 && $scope.isFatalDisabled) &&
  (node.label.indexOf("Error") !== 0 && $scope.isErrorDisabled) &&
  (node.label.indexOf("Warn") !== 0 && $scope.isWarnDisabled) &&
  (node.label.indexOf("Info") !== 0 && $scope.isInfoDisabled) &&
  (node.label.indexOf("Debug") !== 0 && $scope.isDebugDisabled) &&

  (node.label.indexOf("Tomcat") !== 0 && $scope.isTomcatDisabled) &&
  (node.label.indexOf("Agent") !== 0 && $scope.isAgentDisabled) &&
  (node.label.indexOf("Session") !== 0 && $scope.isSessionDisabled) &&
  (node.label.indexOf("Activity") !== 0 && $scope.isActivityDisabled);
  return tmp;
}

//and then I am trying to assign it to an already existing javascript object

$scope.filterTreeOption.isSelectable = func;
```

But this does not take effect. Is this correct way or I am missing something. Please help.

Comment: is not clear the use of node...

Comment: @thegio: `node` is the node object. Check [here](http://wix.github.io/angular-tree-control/#isSelectable)

Comment: seems fine to me, can you show us the HTML where you use that angular tree ? And use your browser's debogguer and add a breakpoint in your function to check if it is really called.

Comment: you should use the opt directive: $scope.opts = {
         isSelectable: function(node) {
             return node.label.indexOf("Node 1") !== 0;
         } 

     };

<treecontrol class="tree-classic" tree-model="treedata" options="opts" on-selection="showSelected(node)">
     label: {{node.label}} ({{node.id}})
 </treecontrol>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value that you should be checking against for `indexOf` is not `0`, which is the first index of the string, but `-1`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

```
$scope.filterTreeOption = {
    dirSelectable: false,
    multiSelection: true,
    injectClasses: {
      "li": "injectedTreeLi"
    }
}

$scope.isFatalDisabled = false; $scope.isErrorDisabled = false; $scope.isWarnDisabled = false; $scope.isInfoDisabled = false; $scope.isDebugDisabled = false; $scope.isTomcatDisabled = false; $scope.isAgentDisabled = false; $scope.isSessionDisabled = false; $scope.isActivityDisabled = false;

// Another function here which changes above boolean property to true if needed.

var func = function(node) {
  var tmp = (node.label.indexOf("Fatal") !== -1 && $scope.isFatalDisabled) &&
  (node.label.indexOf("Error") !== -1 && $scope.isErrorDisabled) &&
  (node.label.indexOf("Warn") !== -1 && $scope.isWarnDisabled) &&
  (node.label.indexOf("Info") !== -1 && $scope.isInfoDisabled) &&
  (node.label.indexOf("Debug") !== -1 && $scope.isDebugDisabled) &&

  (node.label.indexOf("Tomcat") !== -1 && $scope.isTomcatDisabled) &&
  (node.label.indexOf("Agent") !== -1 && $scope.isAgentDisabled) &&
  (node.label.indexOf("Session") !== -1 && $scope.isSessionDisabled) &&
  (node.label.indexOf("Activity") !== -1 && $scope.isActivityDisabled);
  return tmp;
}

//and then I am trying to assign it to an already existing javascript object

$scope.filterTreeOption.isSelectable = func;
```